# Pandas taking more time to execute or even no execution when large input values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The `device.csv` has these values (`head(5)`).

```
    DEVICE_ADDRESS      START_TIME  UPDATE_TIME
0   00:0A:20:46:86:D2   1528711800  1528764903
1   00:0A:20:6A:17:38   1528659901  1528764905
2   00:0A:20:37:4D:C4   1528578901  1528764901
3   00:0A:20:42:96:E8   1528669200  1528764903
4   00:0A:20:3D:DF:5C   1528728729  1528764906
```

Each `DEVICE_MAC` has multiple entries of different `START_TIME, UPDATE_TIME` values. The `CSV` files are red in dataframe, then sorted in ascending order of `Device_address`. Once sorted we will calculate `LATENCY_MIS, LATENCY_RB, RCOUNT` values

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Tool\Device.csv" ,names = [ "DEVICE_MAC", "START_TIME", "UPDATE_TIME"])
df=df.sort_values(['DEVICE_MAC', 'START_TIME', 'UPDATE_TIME'], ascending=[True, True,True])

df['LATENCY_MIS'],df['LATENCY_RB'], df['RCOUNT'], df['PAD'] = 0, 0, 0, 0

mac_ref = df.loc[0,'DEVICE_MAC']
start_refernce_time = df['UPDATE_TIME'].min()
end_reference_time = df['UPDATE_TIME'].max()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(mac_ref == row['DEVICE_MAC']):
        if(index==0):                                                           #Starting of MAC processing
            start_time_ref = row['START_TIME']
            event_time_ref = row['UPDATE_TIME']
            df.loc[index,'RCOUNT'] = 0
            df.loc[index, 'PAD'] = row['UPDATE_TIME'] - start_refernce_time
        elif(row['START_TIME'] == start_time_ref):                              #The same session prevails
            difference_event_ts = row['UPDATE_TIME']-event_time_ref
            event_time_ref = row['UPDATE_TIME']
            df.loc[index,'LATENCY_MIS'] = difference_event_ts -300
            df.loc[index,'RCOUNT'] = 0
            if(index+1 in df.index):
                if(row['DEVICE_MAC']!= df.loc[index+1,'DEVICE_MAC']):
                    df.loc[index, 'PAD'] = end_reference_time -row['UPDATE_TIME']
            if(index== df.index[-1]):
                df.loc[index, 'PAD'] = end_reference_time -row['UPDATE_TIME']
        elif(row['START_TIME'] != start_time_ref):                              #New Session Starts
            #difference_event_ts = row['START_TIME']-event_time_ref+(row['UPDATE_TIME']-row['START_TIME']-300)
            df.loc[index,'LATENCY_RB'] = row['START_TIME']-event_time_ref
            df.loc[index, 'LATENCY_MIS']= row['UPDATE_TIME']-row['START_TIME']        #-300*****
            event_time_ref = row['UPDATE_TIME']
            df.loc[index,'RCOUNT'] = 1
            start_time_ref = row['START_TIME']
            event_time_ref = row['UPDATE_TIME']
    else:                                                                      #Starting of new MAC Processing
        mac_ref = row['DEVICE_MAC'] 
        start_time_ref = row['START_TIME']
        event_time_ref = row['UPDATE_TIME']
        df.loc[index,'RCOUNT'] = 0
        df.loc[index, 'PAD'] = row['UPDATE_TIME'] - start_refernce_time
```

Each row's `LATENCY_MIS, LATENCY_RB, RCOUNT` depends on previous rows and consecutive next row `START_TIME, UPDATE_TIME` values. (Except 1st and last rows of each `DEVICE_MAC` group).
The output looks like this

```
        DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS  START_TIME  UPDATE_TIME LATENCY_MIS LATENCY_RB  RCOUNT  PAD
18228   00:A0:BC:33:04:F0   1527703135  1528787401  1199        0           0       7219
18995   00:A0:BC:33:04:F0   1527703135  1528788601  600         0           0       6019
21007   00:A0:BC:33:04:F0   1527703135  1528791001  1200        0           0       3619
17981   00:A0:BC:37:60:76   1527697084  1528787100  899         0           0       7520
1384    00:A0:BC:3A:91:5C   1528596621  1528766734  599         0           0       27886
2945    00:A0:BC:3A:91:5C   1528596621  1528768533  899         0           0       26087
5832    00:A0:BC:3A:91:5C   1528596621  1528772133  600         0           0       22487
9091    00:A0:BC:3A:91:5C   1528596621  1528776334  600         0           0       18286
11989   00:A0:BC:3A:91:5C   1528596621  1528779934  600         0           0       14686
12880   00:A0:BC:3A:91:5C   1528596621  1528780834  600         0           0       13786
```

The middle code block to calulate `LATENCY_MIS, LATENCY_RB, RCOUNT, PAD` takes more time for executing or not executing when input `CSV` is larger.

Comment: I don't understand the question? You are using `df.iterrows()` for the calculation, so you should expect the computation time to scale with the number of rows. Is there something else?

Comment: I need the optimal code/ alternative for the above logic, so that there is no issues when we execute with larger input items.

Comment: please give us clear info about what you are trying to compute on `LATENCY_MIS`, `LATENCY_RB`, `RCOUNT`, `PAD`

Comment: Let me explain to calculate LATENCY_MIS, so that I will be able to figure out others.
The CSV is sorted on device_MAC_address>start_time>update_time. Then,
LATENCY_MIS is calculated as follows:
1. By default the values are set as 0
2. for every row, if its (start_time == Previous row's start_time), then 
 LATENCY_MIS = update_time - previous row's update_time - 300.               
3. if start_time != Previous row's start_time
 LATENCY_MIS = update_time - start_time.                                                    
Every first row's LATENCY_MIS of every device_MAC_address will be 0.